# How to use R and python in a Kaggle Notebook?

Tags: python, r, rpy2, kaggle

I would like to use both R and Python languages inside a Kaggle Kernel. Thus, when running

```
!pip install rpy2
```

inside a Kaggle Notebook I got the following error

```
Error: rpy2 in API mode cannot be built without R in the PATH or R_HOME defined. Correct this or force ABI mode-only by defining the environment variable RPY2_CFFI_MODE=ABI
```

I've found out a [solution](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/54826) for users of Python within R, but a solution for calling R within Python in a Kaggle Kernel has not yet been provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can notice that a Kaggle Kernel is using behind an anaconda environment. For example,

```
/opt/conda/bin/python3.7
```

Also, it is necessary to have R installed on this conda environment. Thus, we can use the `subprocess` library to run the [following](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-base) script for installing R

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('conda install -c conda-forge r-base', shell=True)
```

and the corresponding `rpy2` package

```
!pip install rpy2
```

I have provided a [notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/amtrema041996/using-rpy2-in-a-kaggle-kernel) on Kaggle with a complete explanation. I'll appreciate your comments.